# Loc function in R?

Tags: r, indexing, location

which(A < B)

Does anyone know which function (if any) will return the index of the
true locations in a Boolean vector?
For instance:

```
A=c(1,3,5,7,4);
B=c(2,4,77,3,3);
X=A<B;
So X is:X
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I'd like to know if there is a function that will tell me the locations of where the TRUE values are?  for instance a vector that will list that the locations are at 1, 2, 3.  This function is sometimes called loc() in other languages.

Comment: `which(A<B)` returns the positions!

Comment: Thankyou, It work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried:

```
which(X %in% TRUE)
```

Comment: Why not just `which(X)`?

Comment: agreed with @DarrenTsai; the `%in% TRUE` part seems like unnecessary obfuscation ...